# c++ std::bind rebind function

Tags: c++, c++11, bind

If I bind a function like this, using placeholders at the time of binding

```
std::bind(memberFunctionPointer, objectPointer, _1, _2);
```

Is it then possible to "rebind" it later to replace some / all of the placeholders, but without calling the function? I want to be able to pass in some parameters and then store it, to be invoked later on. (delayed callback)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `bind` again:

```
auto f = std::bind(memberFunctionPointer, objectPointer, _1, _2);

auto g = std::bind(f, val1, val2);

g();   // (objectPointer->*memberFunctionPointer)(val1, val2)
```

Comment: Note that objects f and g in this example (correctly) have entirely different types. I wanted to bind different objects as they became available/created in different places in my code, and this means the signature used to pass the std::function object has to change as well.